# Self-contained generic memento

Tags: c#, list, generics, reference, memento

Dearest fellow programmers,

I seem to lack some understanding as of how the referencing works in C#.

**The case:**
I tried to implement some sort of Memento proxy which would wrap an interface and store every parameter that we're provided to the method calls and store these into a list.

Whenever necessary we could call the RestoreState and the objects would "reset" to the original state.

**The code:**
*Consumer and model object*

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IMemento memento = new Memento();
        PrestationInfo prestationInfo2 = new PrestationInfo { Advance = 2 };

        memento.Add(prestationInfo2);
        Console.WriteLine(prestationInfo2.Advance);   //Expect 2

        prestationInfo2.Advance = 1;
        Console.WriteLine(prestationInfo2.Advance);   //Expect 1

        memento.RestoreState();
        Console.WriteLine(prestationInfo2.Advance);   //Expect 2, but still 1

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class PrestationInfo
{
    public int Advance { get; set; }
}
```

*Memento*

```
    public interface IMemento
{
    void Add(object pItem);
    void RestoreState();
}


public class Memento : IMemento
{
    public Memento()
    {
        MementoList = new Dictionary<long, object>();
        ReferenceList = new List<object>();
        ObjectIDGenerator = new ObjectIDGenerator();
    }


    private ObjectIDGenerator ObjectIDGenerator { get; set; }
    private Dictionary<long, object> MementoList { get; set; }
    private List<object> ReferenceList { get; set; } 


    public void Add(object pItem)
    {
        bool firstTime;
        long id = ObjectIDGenerator.GetId(pItem, out firstTime);

        if (firstTime)
        {
            var mementoObject = DeepCopy(pItem);
            MementoList.Add(id, mementoObject);

            ReferenceList.Add(pItem);
        }
    }

    public void RestoreState() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ReferenceList.Count; i++)
        {
            object reference = ReferenceList[i];

            bool firstTime;
            long id = ObjectIDGenerator.GetId(reference, out firstTime);

            if (MementoList.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                object mementoObject = MementoList[id];

                reference = mementoObject;
                //reference = PropertyCopy<PrestationInfo>.CopyFrom(mementoObject as PrestationInfo);   //Property copy
                //Interlocked.Exchange(ref reference, mementoObject);   //Also tried this
            }
        }
    }


    private static TCopy DeepCopy<TCopy>(TCopy pObjectToCopy)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, pObjectToCopy);

            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            return (TCopy)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        }
    }
}
```

**Extra info**
My guess is, I'm doing/understand something wrong regarding the List.

I also tried the Interlocked.Exchange, playing around with "ref"'s, using WeakReference's and storing the object into a CareTaker object (and storing that CareTaker into the List), implement some copy Property thing...

And ... I just can't see it.

My expected result would be the PrestationInfo.Advance property containing the value 2. But it keeps

Comment: `prestationInfo2` and the local variable `reference` in `RestoreState` reference the same object, so to change what `prestationInfo2` references you have to change the object, not change the reference value of the local variable `reference`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Change the `Add` method:

```
public long Add(object pItem)
{
    bool firstTime;
    long id = ObjectIDGenerator.GetId(pItem, out firstTime);

    if (firstTime)
    {
        var mementoObject = DeepCopy(pItem);
        MementoList.Add(id, mementoObject);

        ReferenceList.Add(pItem);
    }

    return id;  // i need my memento! LOL
}
```

You should also add this accessor method:

```
public object GetRestoredState(long id)
{
    return MementoList[id];  // you should put some range check here
}
```

Now that you have your id, you can fetch the restored state this way:

```
memento.RestoreState();
prestationInfo2 = memento.GetRestoredState(savedId); // <-- you got this when you called the Add()...
Console.WriteLine(prestationInfo2.Advance);   //Expect 2, but still 1
```

Follow ups: you can also make the `IMemento` into a `IMemento<T>`, and adjust your code accordingly

Comment: This makes sense, but finely walks the line of the memento pattern since you need some key stored somewhere to utilize the memento.

Comment: I seem to understand my mistake now. Together with the comment @Mike Dinescu delivered. 
I could indeed make a map (somewhere in my proxy) that "recognises" the parameters (based on method name/parameter position). Checks out if they exist and if so restore the state.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in your understanding of references in .NET

```
public void RestoreState() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ReferenceList.Count; i++)
    {
        object reference = ReferenceList[i];

        bool firstTime;
        long id = ObjectIDGenerator.GetId(reference, out firstTime);

        if (MementoList.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            object mementoObject = MementoList[id];

            reference = mementoObject;
            //reference = PropertyCopy<PrestationInfo>.CopyFrom(mementoObject as PrestationInfo);   //Property copy
            //Interlocked.Exchange(ref reference, mementoObject);   //Also tried this
        }
    }
}
```

The RestoreState method above does not return anything, and you're strictly operating on references, not their internal state. Inside your method `object reference` is a local reference. It is not the same as the external `prestationInfo2` and your method simply makes `reference` point (refer) to the previously saved copy of the state of `presentationInfo2`.

You could modify it something like this:

```
public object RestoreState() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ReferenceList.Count; i++)
    {
        object reference = ReferenceList[i];

        bool firstTime;
        long id = ObjectIDGenerator.GetId(reference, out firstTime);

        if (MementoList.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            object mementoObject = MementoList[id];

            reference = mementoObject;

            return reference;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
presentationInfo2 = memento.RestoreState();
```

If you want the memento to track objects and *magically* restore their state you will have to make the objects themselves aware of the memento which introduces coupling or use reflection to modify the tracked references internal state. Basically you don't deserialize the persisted state into a new object but use reflection to overwrite the previously stored internal state into the tracked object reference.

Be careful though to store references using WeakReference otherwise you will find yourself with a nice case of memory leak.

Comment: Thanks alot Mike. This realy made me understand my problem! I can work something out with these examples combined with those from @code4life.

Answer (score 0):

Memento.Add needs a ref parameter modifier to access the original reference type pointer.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: The problem is, the RestoreState blows that ref totally away... `reference = mementoObject;`